# DocumentFormat.OpenXml error - the file format and extension of .xslx don't match

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc

I'm using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` library to create excel dynamically in my ASP.Net MVC application(code reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet?view=openxml-2.8.1). The generated excel does have all the data that is required but it throws the below error pop-ups while opening:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone please suggest a fix? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: This error is only thrown when the excel has multiple sheets, for single sheet no error is thrown

Comment: Can you share your XLSX file? This error seems specific to it and in order to resolve it, I'll need to take a look at it.

Comment: Apologies, I can't do it because it contains confidential data